# ASP.NET Controller unittest using Moq verify error

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I'm building an api service using asp.net web api. I'm trying to test my controller using moq but i get the following error

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never
>   performed: x =>x.CreateIncome())

This is the test below

```
[TestClass]
public class IncomeControllerTests
{
    private Mock<IIncomeService> _incomeServiceMock;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        _incomeServiceMock = new Mock<IIncomeService>();

        _incomeServiceMock
            .Setup(x => x.CreateIncome(It.IsAny<Income>())).Verifiable();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Income_Is_Saved_Successfully()
    {
        var incomeController = new IncomeController(_incomeServiceMock.Object);
        Income newIncome = {
            Description = "Income1",
            Amount = 22300,
            Id = 221,
            StaffId = sampleManager.Id,
            Staff = sampleManager,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now
        }

        incomeController.Post(newIncome);
        _incomeServiceMock.Verify(x => x.CreateIncome(newIncome));
    }
}
```

The service used in this controller is injected into my `IncomeController` shown below

**IncomeController.cs**

```
[Authorize]
public class IncomeController : ApiController
{
    private IIncomeService _incomeService;
    public IncomeController(IIncomeService service)
    {
        _incomeService = service;
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]Income values)
    {
        Income income = new Income(
            values.Description,
            values.Amount,
            values.StaffId
            );

        _incomeService.CreateIncome(income);
    }
}
```

**IIncomeService.cs**

```
public interface IIncomeService
{
    void CreateIncome(Income income);
    Income GetIncome(int id);
    List<Income> GetAllIncome();
    Dictionary<string, int> GetMonthlyIncome();
    Dictionary<string, int> GetYearlyIncome();
    void Update(Income income);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to verify using `newIncome` object but in `Post` method you instantiated different instance of the `Income` and pass that to service. These instances are not the same.

You can change your verify statement to something like

```
_incomeServiceMock.Verify(x => x.CreateIncome(It.IsAny<Income>()));
```

or

```
_incomeServiceMock.Verify(x => x.CreateIncome(It.Is<Income>(inc=>
    inc.Description == newIncome.Description 
    && inc.Amount == newIncome.Amount 
    && inc.StuffId == newIncome.StuffId)));
```